# data insert in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

i am actually working on a SQLite database. i am trying to insert data in my database script to display it in a recyclerview later, without entering it via my front side on the application, but directly in the script. how can i do it?
here's my code for better understanding

```
package com.example.tacoskingapp3;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class ArticleManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public ArticleManager(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, "Article.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE articles (IdArticle INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  autoIncrement NOT NULL, NomArticle TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, TypeArticle TEXT NOT NULL, PrixArticle DECIMAL NOT NULL)";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CreateTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVer, int newVer) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...but directly in the script...

Do you want to insert your data into a database with a separate script? (Maybe use the ADB command to execute the script or sth. like that)

I'm afraid that you couldn't. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#DbHelper

[image: android document]

Regards your description, there is a simple demo: `click a button to insert data to DB`, I reuse your code. It looks this this:

```
public class ArticleManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Article.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "articles";
    public static final String KEY_ID_ARTICLE = "IdArticle";
    public static final String KEY_NOM_ARTICLE = "NomArticle";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE_ARTICLE = "TypeArticle";
    public static final String KEY_PRIX_ARTICLE = "PrixArticle";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    KEY_ID_ARTICLE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  autoIncrement NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_NOM_ARTICLE + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ," +
                    KEY_TYPE_ARTICLE + " TEXT NOT NULL ," +
                    KEY_PRIX_ARTICLE + " DECIMAL NOT NULL)";


    public ArticleManager(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        Log.d("ArticleManager", "TANCOLO===> SQL_CREATE_TABLE = " + SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVer, int newVer) {
    }
}
```

```
public class ArticleEntity {
    String NomArticle;
    String TypeArticle;
    double PrixArticle;

    ArticleEntity(String NomArticle, String TypeArticle, double PrixArticle) {
        this.NomArticle = NomArticle;
        this.TypeArticle = TypeArticle;
        this.PrixArticle = PrixArticle;
    }
}
```

```
public class TestSqliteScript extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArticleManager articleManager;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_sqlite_script);

        articleManager = new ArticleManager(this);
        db = articleManager.getWritableDatabase();

        findViewById(R.id.create_data_into_db).setOnClickListener( view ->
                createDataIntoDB()
        );
    }

    private void createDataIntoDB() {
        //step 1, crate ArticleEntity list
        List<ArticleEntity> entities = new ArrayList();
        entities.add(new ArticleEntity("Nom article 01", "type 1", 100.0));
        entities.add(new ArticleEntity("Nom article 02", "type 2", 200.0));
        entities.add(new ArticleEntity("Nom article 03", "type 3", 300.0));
        entities.add(new ArticleEntity("Nom article 04", "type 4", 400.0));

        //step 2, insert the data to DB
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            entities.forEach(entity -> {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(KEY_NOM_ARTICLE, entity.NomArticle);
                values.put(KEY_TYPE_ARTICLE, entity.TypeArticle);
                values.put(KEY_PRIX_ARTICLE, entity.PrixArticle);

                long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                Log.d("TestSqliteScript", "TANCOLO===> newRowId = " + newRowId );
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        db.close();

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

It works:
[image: the screenshot of DB]